# Arrange forms in a m*n grid

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to arrange forms (in this case circles) in a m*n grid.
E.g.: 6 rows with 12 circles each.[image]

The distance between each row and each circle in row should be the same, which is a lot of work doing it manually. How can I automate this with VBA?
The count of rows and elements per row is to be specified. Optionally the size of the whole set of elements in the document.

Comment: You could use a table. That would help you align them.

Comment: Actually, it is quite easy to do manually. Simply insert your first shape, replicate that however many times you need for a single row. Select the lot and use the alignment tools to align them horizontally. Drag the last one to the correct horizontal position. Select the lot and use the alignment tools to distribute them horizontally. Group the lot. Copy & paste for however many rows. Select the lot and use the alignment tools to align them vertically. Drag the last one to the correct vertical position. Select the lot and use the alignment tools to distribute them vertically. Group the lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. I made a little example for you. We start of with a random positioning of shapes

[image]

```
I2 = space between shapes in X direction
J2 = space between shapes in Y direction
I3 = matrix element width
J3 is matrix elemen height
```

The Knop1 is a button with Macro code:

```
Sub Knop1_Klikken()
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xOffset As Double
    Dim yOffset As Double
    Dim matrixW As Integer
    Dim matrixH As Integer
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet
    
    With currentSheet
        xOffset = .Cells(2, 9)
        yOffset = .Cells(2, 10)
        matrixW = .Cells(3, 9)
        matrixH = .Cells(3, 10)
        
        For i = 1 To matrixW
            For j = 1 To matrixH
                k = i + (j - 1) * matrixW
                If k <= .Shapes.Count Then
                    .Shapes(k).Left = i * xOffset
                    .Shapes(k).Top = j * yOffset
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

End result after pressing button:

[image]

You can enhance the code if you want the shapes to fall in the middle of the cells, in this case you do not need the input fields anymore.

Comment: I think the OP was asking for MS Word. Can this be adapted for Word?

Comment: Another MS Office Software ist ok ,too... I'll try it later

Comment: It´s working good so far. How can I add/remove shapes, if I need more/less than there are already on the worksheet?